# Handling orientation change during the asyntask in android

Tags: android-asynctask, android-orientation

I'm currently having a problem in my asyntask. When the progress bar has start and once I rotate the screen, the progress bar disappear and the activity restart. I am trying to use

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

but What if my AsyncTask is not in my activity... Its in another class file common to many activity class. Then how can I get setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR); Thanks for anyone who will help.

Answer (score 0):

this works in my app. I put this line in the manifest.

```
**android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"**
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to this problem:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Device.lockOrientation((Activity)context);
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<Hydrant> hydrants) {
    Device.releaseOrientation((Activity)context);
    ...
}
```

The Device implementation:

```
public class Device {

    public static void lockOrientation(Activity activity) {
        Display display = ((WindowManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int rotation = display.getRotation();
        int tempOrientation = activity.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        int orientation = 0;
        switch(tempOrientation)
        {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
            if(rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90)
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            else
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
            break;
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            if(rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_270)
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
            else
                orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
        }
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
    }

    public static void releaseOrientation(Activity activity) {
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
    }

}
```

As AsyncTasks are only meant to run for a few seconds, this is an acceptable solution to me as this rarely will affect a user. Especially with something as a ProgressDialog giving a nice indication of how long she will have to wait.